# Expansion of $y=\sqrt{1+x+\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon+x}}$

Tags: perturbation-theory

I'm reading "Introduction to Perturbation Methods", Second Edition, by Mark H. Holmes.

In ch 2.2.5 "Matching Revisit" it explains the approach to match the outer and boundary layer solutions, and I got lost in the Example of (2.20) $$y=\sqrt{1+x+\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon+x}}$$
, where $0\le x \le 1$.

First the outer expansion is found for $0<x\le 1$ as (2.21)
$$y\sim \sqrt{1+x} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2x\sqrt{1+x}} + \cdots$$
, and the boundary solution is found by setting $\bar x = x/\varepsilon$ and expanding to obtain (2.22)
$$Y\sim \sqrt{\frac{2+\bar x}{1+ \bar x}} + \frac12 \varepsilon \bar x \sqrt{\frac{2+\bar x}{1+ \bar x}} + \cdots $$

The usual matching approach would be (2.14)
$$\lim_{\bar x\rightarrow\infty}Y_0 = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} y_0$$
, but now it does not work as both solutions become unbounded, so it's necessary to use a more refined matching method.

To do that, introduce the intermediate variable $x_\eta$ defined as (2.17)
$$x_\eta = \frac{x}{\varepsilon^\beta}$$
where $0<\beta<1$. This interval for $\beta$ comes from the requirement that the scaling for the intermediate variable must lie between the outer scale $O(1)$, and the inner scale $O(\varepsilon)$.

Substitute (2.17) into (2.21) gets
$$y_{outer} \sim \sqrt{1+\varepsilon^\beta x_\eta} + \frac{\varepsilon^{1-\beta}}{2x_\eta\sqrt{1+\varepsilon^\beta x_\eta}} + \cdots \sim 1 + \frac12 \varepsilon^\beta x_\eta + \cdots + \varepsilon^{1-\beta} \frac{1}{2x_\eta} + \cdots$$
Similarly, substitute (2.17) into (2.22) gets
$$y_{inner} \sim 1 + \varepsilon^{1-\beta} \frac{1}{2x_\eta} + \cdots + \frac12\varepsilon^\beta x_\eta + \cdots$$

Then it says :

> Comparing these two expansions it is evident that they match.

and stopped just before giving the final result!

**I'm confused here**:

Though $y_{outer}$ and $y_{inner}$ match, both would be unbounded at $x_\eta=0$ or $x_\eta=\infty$.
What value can $\beta$ take?
Any most importantly, what is the final expansion of
$$y=\sqrt{1+x+\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon+x}}$$
?

Comment: Not an answer, but it looks like the expansion is about $\epsilon$, so if $f(\epsilon) = \sqrt{1+x+\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon+x}}$, then $f(\epsilon) \approx f(0) + f'(0) \epsilon = \sqrt{1+x}+ {1 \over 2x \sqrt{1+x}}\epsilon$.

Comment: I must confess that, to me, the steps are not very clear

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, $y_0(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ and $Y_0(\bar{x})=\sqrt{\frac{2+\bar{x}}{1+\bar{x}}}$. I don't see how "both solutions become unbounded" as $x\to 0$ and $\bar{x}\to\infty$.

Comment: It’s not a question on calculus but on perturbation theory, seeking an approximation for $0\le x \le 1$ and small $\varepsilon$. So @copper.hat $f(x,\varepsilon) \approx \sqrt{1+x} + \frac{1}{2x \sqrt{1+x}} \varepsilon$ is not perfect as it cannot handle $x=0$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Indeed. I misread the book and ignore the subscription 0 of $y_0$ and $Y_0$. You are right, thank you for pointing that out!